# store M if the gender type is 0 and store F if gender type is 1using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to store the gender type related to radio box if the user is checked Male it will be stored as a M in database if the user checked Female it will be stored as a F in database 
or (if the user is checked Male the value is '0',if the value is '0'then 'M' will be stored in database  AND   if the user is checked female the value is '1',if the value is '1'then 'F' will be stored in database ........

and my code is like this ....

```
      $terms = "";
      $unique = "";
      $belt = "";
       $beltc = "";
      $email = "";
       $emailc = "";
       $firstname = "";
       $lastname = "";
      $nickname = "";
    $gender = "";
     $weightunit = "";
     $weight = "";
     $dob = "";
      $maxhr = "";
     $phoneno = "";

   if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
if (isset($_POST['terms']))
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];
$unique = $_POST['unique'];
$belt = $_POST['belt'];
$beltc = $_POST['beltc'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailc = $_POST['emailc'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];


            if (isset($_POST['sex']))
        $gender = $_POST['sex'];
        $weightunit = $_POST['weightunit'];
        $phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
        $dob = str_replace(",", "", $_POST['dob']);

       $password = generatePassword();

$ExistingIndex = -1;
$gIndex=0;    
$query = "SELECT gIndex FROM `gym` WHERE gUnique='$unique'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row) {
        $gIndex = $row['gIndex'];
    }
} else {
    //die (mysql_error() . "<br />ResultError:" . $query);
}

$query = "SELECT usrIndex FROM `user` WHERE usrBelt='$belt' AND usrEmail='$email'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row) {
        $ExistingIndex = $row['usrIndex'];
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error() . "<br />ResultError:" . $query;
}

$query = "UPDATE `user` SET usrDeleted=1 WHERE usrBelt='$belt'";
mysql_query($query) or die("Failed Query of " . $query . "<br />" . mysql_error());
$guid = "";
if ($ExistingIndex == -1) {
    $guid = uniqid('Web_', true);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user`(usrBelt,usrFirstname,usrSurname,usrNickname,usrGender,usrEmail,usrMobile,usrDOB,usrWeight,usrWeightUnit,usrGUID,usrPassword,usrMaxHR,usrSIndex)";
    $query.=" VALUES (";
    $query.="'" . mysql_real_escape_string($belt) . "'";
    $query.=",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($firstname) . "'";
    $query.=",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($lastname) . "'";
    $query.=",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($nickname) . "'";
    $query.=",$gender =";
    $query.=",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "'";
    $query.=",''";
    $query.=",'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob)) . "'";
    $query.=",$weight";
    $query.=",$weightunit";
    $query.=",'" . $guid . "'";
    $query.=",'" . md5($password) . "'";
    if (empty($maxhr)) {
        $query.=",NULL";
    } else {
        $query.=",'" . $maxhr . "'";
    }
    $query.=",'" . $gIndex . "'";
    $query.=")";
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE `user` SET ";
    $query.="usrFirstname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($firstname) . "'";
    $query.=",usrSurname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($lastname) . "'";
    $query.=",usrNickname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($nickname) . "'";
    $query.=",usrGender=$gender";
    $query.=",usrEmail='$email'";
    $query.=",usrDOB='" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob)) . "'";
    $query.=",usrWeight=$weight";
    $query.=",usrWeightUnit=$weightunit";
    $query.=",usrPassword='" . md5($password) . "'";
    $query.=",usrDeleted=0";
    $query.=",usrLoggedIn=0";
    if (empty($maxhr)) {
        $query.=",usrMaxHR=NULL";
    } else {
        $query.=",usrMaxHR=" . $maxhr;
    }
    $query.=" WHERE usrIndex=$ExistingIndex";
}
mysql_query($query) or die("Failed Query of " . $query . "<br />" . mysql_error());
```

and  this is the html code

```
        <td style="text-align:right;padding-right:16px;">
                            Male <input type="radio" id="sex_m" name="sex" value="0" <?php if ($gender == '0')
        echo "checked='checked'" ?> onchange="validateRadio('img_sex');" /> Female <input type="radio" id="sex_f" name="sex" value="1" <?php if ($gender == '1')
                                        echo "checked='checked'" ?> onchange="validateRadio('img_sex');" />
                        </td>
```

I want to change the if user checked the Male checkbox the value M will be stored in the database (or) if the user checked the Male checkbox then the default value is  "0" it will be converted to    "m"

this will be done to the Female type check box too...

can any one help on this.......

Comment: -0.35 for still using `mysql_query` and building SQL strings by hand.

Comment: I would advise you to study more object-oriented scripting methods. This code could be 90% lighter and much more transparent if done smarter.

Comment: i am very sorry the actual question is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038123/how-do-i-change-the-database-values-using-php-and-mysql  would  u pls take a look at this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a joke or something, but anyway:

```
if( $_POST['sex'] == 0 ) {
    $gender = 'M';
}
else {
    $gender = 'F';
}
```

Or, you know, just use M and F as the form values in the first place.

Comment: i am very sorry for defining  this question

Comment: No need to be sorry, the answer is just so obvious that I'm wondering if I really understood the question correctly.

Comment: i am very sorry the actual question is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038123/how-do-i-change-the-database-values-using-php-and-mysql  would  u pls take a look at this one